# How to get EXM Campign data from x-connect odata service

Tags: xconnect, exm

My requirement is to get

1. triggered email campaign report data from x-connect odata api (https://xccollect/odata)
   wanted to get data like : email open and click rate , bounce email,spam complain, failed recipients etc.

I tried to to hit x-connect end point - https://xccollect/odata/Contacts or https:xccollect/odata/Interactions. Still i can't find any email campaign statics information in this.

Could you please guide me how to extract Exm campaign report using x-connect api

Note : Sitecore version i am using :sitecore 9.3 initial release.

Thanks in advance !
Pushpendra